# Why the set of all maximum points of a continuous function is a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on domain $\Omega$ and its maximum value is $m$. Let $M={\{x|f(x)=m\}}$, then how do I prove $M$ is a closed set? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because $M = f^{-1}(\{m\})$ is the [pre-image of a closed set by a continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces), hence closed. In fact, you can put there any number other than $m$ and the same history goes.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x \notin M$, then $f(x) \neq m$ and since $f$ is continuous, there is some open $U$ containing $x$ such that $f(y) \neq m$ for all $y \in U$, hence $M^c$ is open.